# How to change text-color from black to white while scrolling over images

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am building a website with a lot of images. On the sidebar is a text (which stays in place with position: sticky), I would like it to change its color from black to white while overlapping the images it passes while scrolling down the webpage. How do I do that?

I found a Codepen-example, doing exactly this. But it's complicated to extract the requested code since the Javascript also handles a scrolling animation.
https://codepen.io/Atise/pen/WNOmyxY

My sidenav functions like this one: https://codepen.io/clairecodes/pen/bvWKdr

**I have given this a second though**t: The problem with this approach is that it won't work on an ordinary website while scrolling through its length vertically. The white text should only be visible when approached by the navbar. To make this work, the images needs to have some trigger that shows the text (*.section-title.on-dark*) only when being approached by the navbar.

```
<div class="outer-container">
    <div class="image-container" style="background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1570528812862-9984124e7e22?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=85&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=srgb&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ');">
    
    <style>
      body {
     margin: 0;
     min-height: 3000px;
     font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}
 .outer-container {
     max-width: 600px;
     margin: auto;
     width: 90%;
     padding: 200px 0px;
     position: relative;
}
 .image-container {
     padding-bottom: 100%;
     background: black;
     position: relative;
     overflow: hidden;
     z-index: 2;
     background-size: cover;
     background-position: center;
}
 .section-title {
     margin: 0;
     font-size: 64px;
     width: 100%;
     text-align: center;
     position: absolute;
     top: 50%;
     left: -30%;
     transform: translateY(-50%);
     z-index: 1;
     white-space: nowrap;
}
 .section-title.on-dark {
     color: white;
}
 .section-title span {
     position: relative;
     display: block;
}
    </style>
    
        <h2 class="section-title on-dark">
            <span class="paralax-title">
                Live The Adventure
            </span>
        </h2>
    </div>
    
    <h2 class="section-title">
        <span class="paralax-title">
            Live The Adventure
        </span>
    </h2>
</div>

    <script>
      let didScroll = false;
let paralaxTitles = document.querySelectorAll('.paralax-title');

const scrollInProgress = () => {
    didScroll = true
}
const raf = () => {
    if(didScroll) {
        paralaxTitles.forEach((element, index) => {
            element.style.transform = "translateX("+ window.scrollY / 10 + "%)"
        })
        didScroll = false;
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(raf);
}
requestAnimationFrame(raf);
window.addEventListener('scroll', scrollInProgress)
    </script>
```

Comment: In the snippet there are two texts; a black one that shows outside the image and other on white. If you change the first occurrence on the HTML you can see how it works. So your solution could have that approach?

Comment: Please could you show us your own code structure. In particular I don’t understand how you are keeping your sidebar in place during scrolling if you have set it as absolute. And how much text is there?

Comment: The sidenav functions like this (I have removed position absolute):
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_sidenav_fixed2

Answer (score 0):

You're prebably looking for `mix-blend-mode`.

```css
.bg {
  width: 200vw;
  height: 200vh;
  background-image: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/7718429/pexels-photo-7718429.jpeg);
  background-size: cover;
}

.text {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  color: white;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">
  <h1 class="text">Lorem Ipsum</h1>
</div>
```

There are values other that `difference`. Read the [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode) and find the value that best suits your website.

Comment: The color of the sidebar text is black because this "mix-blend-mode" doesn't work.